# Calling an interface in Flow.create {}

Tags: origen-sdk

I am just checking this out if it works. I added a custom tml definition under origen_testers folder under my home directory inside ".origen" area. The TEST_METHODS block was added in the file "custom_tml.rb"

```
    module OrigenTesters
  module SmartestBasedTester
    class Base
      class TestMethods
        class CustomTml < BaseTml
          def initialize(test_methods, definitions)
            @definitions = definitions
            @klass = definitions[:class_name]
            super test_methods
          end
      TEST_METHODS = {

            my_custom_tm:              {
              class_name:  'mylib.mytm',
              param1:     [:string, ''],
              param2:     [:string, '']
            },

          }
          def klass
            @klass || ''
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end<p>
```

In my flow.create when generating a testflow file, how would i call this interface so i can use the newly added my_custom_tm testmethod? I tried **Flow.create Interface: 'OrigenTesters'** and that didnt work..Do I have to use the "::" and specify all the way to "Customtml"

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation you need to review in order:

1. [Creating your own test interface](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/interface/)
2. [Creating custom test methods](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Custom_Test_Methods)

You should never have to make classes in the `OrigenTesters` namespace to do what you want to do.

regards